# Is there a way to avoid multiple html.unescape calls in Python 3?

Tags: python, html

So I've been trying to get rid of special HTML characters and used html.unescape for that. The problem is if there are 2 special characters in a row the functions doesn't really work how I would've wanted

I tried multiple function calls like html.unescape(html.unescape(text)), but surely that's a terrible idea

```
str='Anchor says Buckingham Palace pressure killed ABC&amp;#39;s story on Epstein'
print(html.unescape(str))
```

So instead of getting all the characters replaced, the output is:

```
Anchor says Buckingham Palace pressure killed ABC&#39;s story on Epstein
```

Is there a way to deal with this kind of a problem?

Comment: Two `unescape` calls are are required here because the string has been escaped twice.

Comment: But technically, you might need to call this function more than twice, how do you control to make sure all characters are unescaped?

Comment: You should unescape as many times as the string is escaped. Presumably the string comes from an API of some sort, which escapes the string more than once (which is strange), but at least it escapes it a predictable number of times (2 in this case).

Comment: You generally should only need to unescape once. If it still has entities in it, it should be because the text was trying to display the entity literally. E.g. `The HTML entity for & is &amp;`

Comment: If it has actually been escaped multiple times, that's usually a bug in the source of the data. Or maybe your code mistakenly escaped data that was already escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments are right when they say that there is usually something wrong with our data when it is escaped multiple levels deep. However, if we want to accept this problem as it is, and still need to solve it, so if we receive a string that is escaped potentially multiple times, and we do not know how often it is escaped, we could just unescape the heck out of it, i.e. until it does not change any more.

We could do this with a `while`-loop as follows:

```
import html


def ultimately_unescape(s: str) -> str:
    unescaped = ""
    while unescaped != s:
        s = html.unescape(s)
        unescaped = html.unescape(s)

    return s
```

which gives us:

```
>>> ultimately_unescape("Anchor says Buckingham Palace pressure killed ABC&amp;#39;s story on Epstein"))
"Anchor says Buckingham Palace pressure killed ABC's story on Epstein"
```